# dojo widgetlist passing value to template

Tags: dojo

When trying to use an at() value in the widgetlist data-mvc-child-props property, i get an error
dojox.mobile.ListItem template:erpValue

But if i assign that value to a static string it works fine. ex erpValue:"SomeValue"
From the documentation it seems that this should work, since i see then mapping label values to at()

```
        <ul class="searchProductList" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList" id="repeatId1" class="tabletProductList"
                    data-dojo-props='children: searchv2.productList.items'
                    data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mvc/WidgetList,dojox/mvc/_InlineTemplateMixin"
                    data-mvc-child-type="dojox/mvc/Templated"
                    data-mvc-child-mixins="dojox/mobile/ListItem"
                    data-mvc-child-props="clickable: true, 
                                            indexAtStartup: this.indexAtStartup,
                                            variableHeight : 'true',
                                            erpValue: at(this.target, 'erpPartNumber'),
                                            uniqueid: at(this.target, 'uniqueId'),
                                            onClick: function(e){                                                   
                                                console.log('Target::' + JSON.stringify(this.target));
                                                console.log(this.indexAtStartup); return true;}">
                <script type="dojox/mvc/InlineTemplate">
                    <div class="mblListItemLabel">
                        <div class="productListContent"
                            data-uniqueid="${erpValue}">
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                     </script>
          </ul>
```

I know the value gets assigned because when i grab the widget and do a widget.get("erpValue").  the correct value shows up.

Full Error::

```
Uncaught Error: dojox.mobile.ListItem template:erpValue core-web-layer.js:300
(anonymous function) core-web-layer.js:300
(anonymous function) dojo.js:39
(anonymous function) core-web-layer.js:168
g.substitute core-web-layer.js:168
j._stringRepl core-web-layer.js:300
j.buildRendering core-web-layer.js:300
b core-web-layer.js:108
i.buildRendering core-web-layer.js:56
b core-web-layer.js:108
e.buildRendering mobile-ui-layer.js:24
b core-web-layer.js:108
e.buildRendering mobile-ui-layer.js:297
e.create core-web-layer.js:337
e.postscript core-web-layer.js:336
h.around.advice dojo.js:97
i.(anonymous function).h dojo.js:96
(anonymous function) core-web-layer.js:110
(anonymous function) WidgetList.js:193
i.map dojo.js:52
create WidgetList.js:181
declare._buildChildren.lang.hitch._buildChildrenSeq WidgetList.js:198
(anonymous function) dojo.js:38
P dojo.js:18
(anonymous function) dojo.js:11
Q dojo.js:19
xa dojo.js:11
a dojo.js:11
declare._buildChildren WidgetList.js:212
(anonymous function) WidgetList.js:157
lang.mixin.watchElements.callbacks._watchElementCallbacks StatefulArray.js:141
lang.mixin.splice StatefulArray.js:87
lang.mixin.push StatefulArray.js:47
(anonymous function) searchv2.js:142
(anonymous function) base.js:757
i.forEach dojo.js:52
searchv2.populateList searchv2.js:141
(anonymous function) base.js:757
onInvokeProcedureSuccess wlclient.js:1838
window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onSuccess worklight.js:1439
window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlSuccess worklight.js:1398
(anonymous function) base.js:757
window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyState base.js:965
window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChange base.js:904
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: What is the full error message and on which line does it occur?

Comment: Put the full error above

Comment: ok, this must be a bug, it works in 1.9.3... but not in 1.8.1.will have to see if i can upgrade